# mootools formcheck : regex for number validation

Tags: regex, validation, forms, mootools, numbers

i need to validate currency field with [formcheck](http://mootools.floor.ch/docs/formcheck/files/formcheck-js.html) plugin for mootools.
It has number validation type, and number accepts regex to personalize validation.

I need sample to validate:

```
1.000,01   --> ok
1,000.02   --> not ok
1000,12    --> ok
1000.13    --> not ok
10.000     --> ok
100.00     --> not ok
```

and so on.
Can you help me please?

thanks.

Comment: check http://download.mootools.net/forge/p/meiomask or http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/imask/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^\d+(?:\.\d\d\d)*(,\d\d)?$`

I'm assuming `.` is your thousands separator, `,` is the decimal separator, and the comma must always be followed by two digits if it's present.

Answer (score 0):

This will pass all your tests:

```
^(\d|\.\d{3}|,\d+$)*$
```

If you want to require at least one digit, use:

```
^\d(\d|\.\d{3}|,\d+$)*$
```